# solrj setting query fields

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Am using the below solr query which works

```
https://host:port/solr/ref_cm/select?defType=edismax&q=abc&qf=a+b+c+d
```

May I know how to set the same using solrj. I tried below with "qf" but it doesnt work (even though from url it works)

```
final Map<String, String> queryParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

queryParamMap.put("q", query);
queryParamMap.put("defType", "edismax");
queryParamMap.put("qf","a, b, c, d");
```

Appreciate any pointers

Comment: The Solr log can show you exactly what request was sent to Solr; that's probably a good place to start. You probably want to include the complete code that makes the request as well.

Comment: can you try the queryParamMap.put("qf", "a b c d");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below part of the code. it should work for you.

The code `queryParamMap.put("qf", "a b c d")` would work instead of `queryParamMap.put("qf","a, b, c, d")`.

The full code would be something like below.

```
ModifiableSolrParams queryParamMap= new ModifiableSolrParams();
queryParamMap.set("q", "test");
queryParamMap.set("defType", "edismax");
queryParamMap.set("qf", "a b c d");
QueryResponse qResp = cloudSolrClient.query(queryParamMap);
SolrDocumentList docList = qResp.getResults();
int numFound = (int) docList.getNumFound();
```